# WebDav with Curl

Tags: c#, curl, webdav

I am using Windows Service to start a WebDAV server which is written in C#.

I want to use the **curl** tool to upload the files to the server.

I am using `curl -T c:/a.txt to http://localhost:9000/` command to upload the file.

It is neither throwing any exception nor uploading the file.

Any idea why this issue is happening?

Comment: There seems to be a superfluous `to` in the command line. Then add `-v` to get more information about what's (not) going on.

Comment: pretty good when the creator of curl comments on your question :)